# Modules and custom Input functions Mathematica

Tags: module, wolfram-mathematica

I am trying to make a Module that takes a Boolean function, and prints the following:

- the function's truth table
- the function's NOR epxression
- the function's minimal Disjunctive normal form

So far I have the following:

```
Module[{f}, f[x_, y_] := Input["Enter Boolean function"]; 
Print[BooleanTable[f[x_, y_], {x_, y_}]]; 
Print[BooleanConvert[f[x_, y_], NOR]]; 
Print[BooleanMinimize[f[x_, y_]]]]
```

However, for every `Print` I need to reenter the Boolean function. How do I make every expression to use the same Boolean function without having to reenter it 3 times?

Comment: Try changing f[x_, y_] := Input to f[x_, y_] = Input

Comment: That worked, thanks. I thought you needed := for defining functions, though, so what was the problem there?

Comment: You should try to find a good understandable description of the difference between and use of = and :=. That will greatly help you in the future. Roughly, = assigns the right hand side to the left hand side immediately and := just stores the right hand side to be done in the future when you use the left hand side. So your := did Input each time you used your f. But with = it did the Input immediately and assigned that result to f. This is why you had three input boxes with := but only one with =. There is lots more to learn and understand about this and I will let you go find and do that now.

Comment: You should also look for a good understandable description of when to use a trailing _ and when to not use that. The way you are using _ on each line except the first is not the normal style and I'm surprised that it even works. I realize that Mathematica notation is different from many other programming languages and this can be really confusing.